# How photon would be seen by accelerated particle?

Tags: visible-light, photons, speed

If we accelerate a particle in LHC Accelerator to 99.9999991% of speed of light, and add during the experiment a beam of light to that speedway, what velocity of photon from that lightbeam would be seen by particle?

a) speed of light is the same for all observers

b) particle will see photon moving 0,0000009% faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course a). But there is the Doppler effect: the proton will see a gamma photon. If it is an electron beam in a synchrotron, lasers can be used in the inverse Compton effect to make gamma-prime photons.